# C# Check Sum CRC16 CCITT

Tags: c#, checksum, crc16

Although I am following the method to calculate Check Sum CRC16. I'm cant get the result as user manual show. Can anyone help on this?

```cs
private static UInt16 CRC16_Update(UInt16 crc, byte c)
{
    crc = (((ushort)(((crc >> 4) & 0x0FFF) ^ crc_tab[((crc ^ c) & 0x000F)])));
    crc = (((ushort)(((crc >> 4) & 0x0FFF) ^ crc_tab[((crc ^ (c >> 4)) & 0x000F)])));
    return crc;
}
```

Command Format:

[image: Command Format]

CRC Manual Example:

[image: CRC Manual Example]

Manual Command example:

[image: Manual Command example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just initialize crc result to 0xFFFF not zero as I expect.
such:

```
byte[] data = new byte[] { 0x3F, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x06, 0x8C, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0xCD, 0x13 };
    
UInt16 crc = 0xFFFF;
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length-2; i++)
{
  crc = CRC16_Update(crc, data[i]);
}
```